# How to dynamically load and display translations in TWIG from PHP variables?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to make the trans('key' : value) method work by providing the variables either by PHP or preparing them on TWIG, both without any success so far.

So far I have tried to send the full line from the PHP Controller, which would be

```
{{bodymail| trans({'%user.name%': user.name,'%user.surname%': user.surname}) | raw}}
```

The following above works correctly when hard-coded, but when sending/composing it, it displays either the above code literally, or the correct message but without applying the translations.

This is something else I have tried, now on TWIG itself

```
{% set message = "'"~bodymail~"'| trans({" %}
{% for sub in variables %}
  {% set message = message~"'%"~sub~"%': "~sub~"," %}
{% endfor %}
{% set message = message | trim (',', 'right') %}
{% set message = message~"}) | raw" %}
{{message}}
```

Code above is something I also tried for constructing the whole thing in TWIG itself... which resulted in directly not rendering the bodymail message (reference to .yml file).

Trying to make it work as a generic for anything that I input following the format (now i'm using user.name and user.surname, but I might want to use product references later for example).

Comment: Could you add the result of the first piece of code please. Also try without "dot" as `{'%user_name%': user.name`

Comment: `Appreciated Username Surname`. (but with real username and surname data) This is the one that works fine, but because it's hardcoded. When trying to reproduce the same dynamically, it shows either literally the first snippet of code, or `Appreciated user.name user.surname`.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but I keep getting the same result. It prints literally the first snippet instead of the translations + variables. I can't seem to find a way to make TWIG read that correctly instead of literally.

Comment: `'app.greetings'| trans({'%user_name%': user.name,'%user_surname%': user.surname}) | raw`
This is what I'm getting now in the view instead of `Appreciated Username Surname`